# how to relate two mysql tables that are not directly connected through a key

Tags: mysql

I have the following two mysql tables.

**Table Name: Analysis**

```
id   execution_time
---  --------------
A1   1
A2   20
A3   35
```

**Table Name: Bugs**

```
bug_id creation_time
------ -------------
1000   1.1
1001   1.3
1002   20.2
1003   20.7
1004   20.9
1005   35.1
```

Bugs 1000, 1001 are created for the Analysis A1

Bugs 1002, 1003, 1004 are created for Analysis A2

Bug 1005 is created for Analysis A3

So, Bug creation_time is always greater than the execution_time of its Analysis and bug_creation_time is always less than the execution of the later analyses.

Now, 1) how can I find the related bugs (bug_id) given that I have an analysis id.

2) how can I find the related analysis id for a given bug data (id, creation_time)

Comment: WHy does bug 1004 exist twice in this table? Why does it account for analysis A3? Your logic doesn't explain itself.

Comment: Sorry, was a mistake. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)**
[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://rextester.com/BSMBI42310)

```
SELECT b.*, t.*
FROM Bugs b
CROSS JOIN (  SELECT a1.id, 
                     a1.`execution_time` as `start_time`, 
                     a2.`execution_time` as `end_time`
              FROM Analysis a1
              LEFT JOIN Analysis a2
                 ON a1.`execution_time` < a2.`execution_time`  
              WHERE a2.`execution_time` IS NULL
                 OR a2.`execution_time`  = (SELECT min( z.`execution_time`)
                                            FROM Analysis z
                                            WHERE z.`execution_time` > a1.`execution_time`)
            ) t
WHERE b.`creation_time` between `start_time` and `end_time`
   or (b.`creation_time` > `start_time` and `end_time` IS NULL)
```

**OUTPUT:** *only need filter by id*

[image]

**2)**

```
SELECT *
FROM Analysis a
WHERE a.id = (  SELECT MAX(id)
                FROM Analysis a
                WHERE a.execution_time < @bugCreationTime)
```

Comment: If the execution time of an analysis increases by more than 1, the solution 1) would not work. In that case, how would 1) look like? Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes I saw you change your question. Working on it. what about 2)?

Comment: wow! i didn't expect 1.2 to be this big. Thanks a lot Juan. BTW. I am wondering why do I have negative votes on this question.

Comment: Not sure, sometime ppl dont understand the question and blame the writer. But I think is because that table design is very weird. Is more efficient you create a FK on `Bugs` pointing the `Analysis` table then the query would be much more simple.

Comment: I have simplified the example. The actual problem is much bigger and the actual design is missing a FK. 

I worked with sql about 10 years ago and have forgotten many things over the years. Thanks a lot for your thought Juan.

Comment: I tried to find the option earlier to accept, but couldn't find the tick button. Thanks for the reminder :)